# Is there a word that describes an individual who is always clueless when he has to face major challenges?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

If a person does not have the ability to reason logically in  high pressure situations (and is consequently always clueless), what term can be used to describe such a person? I'm looking for an adjective but a noun will also do.

If there is a medical term to describe such a condition I will be interested in knowing about that as well.

Example Sentence:

> He sank into stormy contemplation, clueless how to handle the latest
>   of his challenges.

So from the above example, such a person can be called a __________

Comment: [perpetually clueless](https://www.google.com/search?q="perpetually+clueless")?

Comment: Also, is this person clueless only about people, but about everything?

Comment: Also write if you need a medical term for such an inability to reason logically or something?

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. The only other change I would recommend is to add why you don't just want to use the word "clueless," or one of its synonyms as found in a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/clueless?s=t). For example, maybe none of these words have the right nuance of meaning. Describing this will help show what kind of word you do want.

Comment: Related medical terms are "Hyperemotivity", "Prostration" or "Avolition". But none of them perfectly fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [nonplus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonplus) - It means

> (noun) A state of bafflement or perplexity : quandary
>
> (adjective) caused to be at a loss as to what to **think**, say, or do.

Also, consider another noun [Quandary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quandary) which is a synonym of [perplexity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perplexity)
It means

> A situation in which you are confused about what to do

Answer (score 1):

This person is ***ineffectual*** (adj), which [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ineffectual) defines as:

> Lacking forcefulness or effectiveness; inadequate or incompetent: an
>   ineffectual ruler; ineffectual in dealing with a problem

Sentence (made up)

> In a high pressure situation, an ineffectual person will either freeze or will make random stabs at doing something, anything, but they will add up to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Another adjective that might fit is ***blithe***. Merriam Webster defines it thus:

> "Showing a lack of proper thought or care : not caring or worrying."